# Total dose count with drop off period

Tags: r

I want to produce R script for the following dummy data output.

For a given route on a given date, there is a dosage, which accumulates for each extra dose given for each following date (total dosage variable). 7 days after the date of administration (date variable), the total dosage reduces by the dosage on that given date, as illustrated in the dummy data table below.  This varies the ‘date’ + 7 days’ variable values.  I want to create the ‘total dosage’ and ‘date’ + 7 days’ variables.  I also want to create a variable for the ‘interval to next date’, with the final date given a 24 hour interval value.

Dummy data

```
'id'   ‘date’          ‘route’         'form'   ‘dosage’                 
 1     10.01.23            patch          pc       30mg                       
 1     11.01.23            patch          pc       30mg                       
 1     12.01.23            patch          pc       30mg        
 1     20.01.23            patch          pc       30mg
```

Desired output 1

```
'id'   ‘date’                   ’route’         'form’      dosage’     ‘total dosage’      ‘dosage after ‘date’ + 7 days’          
1       10.01.23                patch               pc          30mg            30mg                        30mg
1       11.01.23                patch               pc          30mg            60mg                        60mg
1       12.01.23                patch               pc          30mg            90mg                        90mg
1       20.01.23                patch               pc          30mg            30mg                        30mg
```

Desired output 2

```
'id'   ‘date’           ‘interval to next date’         ’route’         'form’      dosage’     ‘total dosage’      ‘dosage after ‘date’ + 7 days’          
1       10.01.23                1                       patch            pc         30mg            30mg                        30mg
1       11.01.23                1                       patch            pc         30mg            60mg                        60mg
1       12.01.23                8                       patch            pc         30mg            90mg                        90mg
1       20.01.23                24                      patch            pc         30mg            30mg                        30mg
```

Comment: could you separate your table to 1) initial dummy data and  2) desired transformed data

Comment: Thank you, I have added the dummy data and desired output format as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dplyr package for this. First, calculate the 'dosage_group' according to breaks between dosages. Then group by the dosage group and calculate the cumulative sum for the total dosage.

dosage_after_date_plus_7_days is a bit tricky. You first need to save the dataframe to a variable, then use `rowwise` for calculating dosages after 7 days for each row.

```
#install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  date = c("10.01.23", "11.01.23", "12.01.23", "20.01.23"),
  route = rep("patch", 4),
  dosage = rep("30mg", 4)
)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = "%d.%m.%y"),
         date_diff = c(0, diff(date)), # calculate breaks between dosages
         dosage_group = 1, # create a "group" for each consecutive dosage in 7 days
         dosage_group = coalesce(lag(dosage_group), 1) + ifelse(date_diff > 7, 1, 0), # increment the group if there is a break
         dosage_num = as.numeric(sub("mg", "", dosage)), #convert dosage to numeric
         ) %>% 
  group_by(dosage_group) %>% 
  mutate(total_dosage = paste0(cumsum(dosage_num),"mg")) %>% 
  ungroup()

df <- df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    dosage_after_date_plus_7_days = paste0(sum(df$dosage_num[df$date <= date + 7 & df$date > date]), "mg")
  ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-c(date_diff, dosage_group, dosage_num) ) # remove helper variables

print(df)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   date       route dosage total_dosage dosage_after_date_plus_7_days
#>   <date>     <chr> <chr>  <chr>        <chr>                        
#> 1 2023-01-10 patch 30mg   30mg         60mg                         
#> 2 2023-01-11 patch 30mg   60mg         30mg                         
#> 3 2023-01-12 patch 30mg   90mg         0mg                          
#> 4 2023-01-20 patch 30mg   30mg         0mg
```

Comment: Thank you, your code works great for the example I gave.  I realised afterwards, that I need to take in to account the route and form to differentiate between rows.  I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: I amended the desired output file, as the dosage_after_date_plus_7_days was incorrect... the dosage should accumulate for 7 days and then drop away.